# How to go back when redirceted to external URL? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have implemented redirect to external url like this:

```
{ path: 'test', component: RandomComponent, resolve: {url: 'externalUrlRedirectResolver'},data: {externalUrl: 'http://www.google.com'}}

providers: [
{
    provide: 'externalUrlRedirectResolver',
    useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) =>
    {
        window.location.href = (route.data as any).externalUrl;
    }
}]
```

My problem is: When I click back button after redirect. I am redirected back to /test route which again redirects me to http://www.google.com and than again when I click back, it takes me back to previous page (/homepage). Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you can use ``skipLocationChange`` when redirect to test path

Comment: Yeah this helped! Got it working, thank you!